# Input security for post PHP

Tags: php, security, xss, code-injection

I´ve a doubt about SECURITY linked to POST data in PHP.

The context:

I´ve several input (text, email, radio) and some textarea.
EG

```
<input type="text" name="entries[]"> /* Input ARRAY */

<input type="text" name="username"> 

<textarea name="message[]">...</textarea> /* Textarea ARRAY */
```

What I´m doing is sending all the values to the *.php page and then, I print all of them
EG

```
if($_POST)
{
$entries = htmlspecialchars("$_POST['entries']", ENT_QUOTES);
$username = htmlspecialchars("$_POST['username']", ENT_QUOTES);
$message = htmlspecialchars("$_POST['message']", ENT_QUOTES);

echo $username;
echo...
echo...
}
```

**I do not know too much about security. Is it ok JUST with htmlspecialchars...?
Or Have I to use other functions?**

The data is JUST to print with echo on the *.php page (no MYSQL)

And yes, my doubt is about the cide that the user can put on each INPUT, because I don´t want to limitate their contents just to text or numbers, or similar.

Thanks.

Comment: `$_POST['entries']` and `$_POST['message']` are arrays, not strings, so you have to loop over all the elements.

Comment: Use `mysqli_escape_string()` function

Comment: @aldrin27 That's only when putting them into SQL queries, not displaying them on a webpage.

Comment: in short yes,htmlspecialchars() is fine for just displaying on a web page.

Comment: @Barmar he said Input security from posts

Comment: @aldrin27 Look at his code. He's just echoing them, he's not doing anything with MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop over the arrays.

```
$entries = array_map('htmlentities', $_POST['entries']);
$username = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
$message = array_map('htmlentities', $_POST['message']);
```

or to include `ENT_QUOTES` you can use:

```
$entries = array_map(function($x) {
    return htmlentities($x, ENT_QUOTES);
}, $_POST['entries']);
```

and similarly for `$message`.

Comment: Think it should have quotes encoded as well, `ENT_QUOTES`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a lot! One doubt... For variables with ENT_QUOTES is... htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES);  but for the array...? Thanks again!

Comment: I've added how you can use an anonymous function to give additional arguments like `ENT_QUOTES`.